# Pydev/OpenCV: Installation Errors

Tags: python, eclipse, opencv, pydev

I've a **Mac (OS X 10.7.3 64 bit)** and am working with `OpenCV and Python`.

I was able to **install OpenCV using MacPorts** with support for Python.

I installed the **2.7 Python interpreter**, exported the site-packages to `PYTHONPATH`(this is where the location of my `cv2.so and cv.py` are).

I am able to run my `OpenCV Python programs` via the command line.

I installed **Eclipse + PyDev**, chose the same interpreter.

Now, in the Project properties for any project I create, I add the **site-packages dir** in the system libraries. If I save and run, I get the following error:

> File
>   "/Users/harishvenkatesan/Documents/Eclipseworkspace/helloworldpython/src/org/eclipse/python/standard.py",
>   line 10, in `<module>`

```
import cv
```

> File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py",
>   line 1, in `<module>`

```
from cv2.cv import *
```

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_cv2)

It seems like PyDev found the location alright, since from `cv2.cv import *` is the statement in cv.py. But I am not able to fix this error. I did a few searches online, but couldn't find any solutions.

Does anyone have an idea about this? Much appreciated! My Eclipse and everything else is 64-bit, so I am not sure if this is a 32-64 bit mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
import cv
```

I use

```
import cv2.cv as cv
```

and it works.
Hope it will work for you too :)